# pgShapeLoader: how to load a shapefile in a different schema than 'public'

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to load a shapefile in PostGIS using pgShapeLoader.

It works but I can load table only in the "public" schema and I don't know how to configure, the tool to upload my shapefile in another schema.

Is it possible?

Any suggestion for workaround?

Anyway I can use shp2pgsql and then psql from command line in PostGIS...

Answer (score 6):

The **pgShapeloader** tool has the ability to upload a shapefile in a different schema than *public*.

Just double click the **public** word and type your schema name instead:

[image]